# Options for full stack testing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, selenium, cucumber

There are quite a number of options for **Full-Stack testing** of Rails applications.  Some use real browsers, some are headless, some don't run javascript at all.

**Which tools do you use or recommend and why?**

List of **browser simulators or automators**:

- Rails built-in support for integration and functional tests (no JS)
- Webrat
- Webrat::selenium
- Selenium
- Celerity (through Culerity)
- Watir
- ...

List of **testing DSLs and frameworks**:

- Rails defaults (assertions, ...)
- Shoulda
- Cucumber
- Capybara (unified DSL for several browser simulators)
- ...

Comment: Bummer...  all good answers, but which is the best?

Answer (score 2):

All rails applications benefit from a good coverage of unit and functional tests, whether you use rspec or shoulda etc, is mostly a matter of personal preference. I'm a fan of `shoulda` mostly for the context blocks it provides, making setting up test scenarios much easier and clearer to understand.

I don't think browser simulators/automators are needed unless your application is quite javascript heavy. I'd recommend only using them to test javascript, and for that purpose it's definitely better to go with driving a real browser than to simulate. The app I'm working on now is quite javascript heavy and we're using `cucumber` along with `watir`/`firewatir` to run our cucumber tests in firefox for the javascript driven functions on our site.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a bunch of things during my Rails career over the last few years.

Currently working on a pretty large Rails app on JRuby with very solid test coverage and our stack looks like the following.

Unit Testing:

- RSpec coverage of models, helpers, libraries and controllers. Controller coverage tends to be very high-level
- JSpec coverage for a project that is using some pretty cutting edge JS and HTML 5 wizardry

Functional Testing:

- Cucumber using Capybara and Culerity (we just converted from WebRat in order to get coverage of JS-heavy front-ends from Cucumber)
- Selenium that is now "legacy" and slowly being migrated to cucumber/capybara

Answer (score 1):

In the project I'm currently working on, for testing the full stack we're using Cucumber with capybara as the driver.

The front end is very javascript heavy, I've tried a couple of headless browser drivers (capybara-envjs and akephalos), but both were incorrectly failing tests that passed in a real browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Cucumber + Capybara with a combination of selenium-webdriver and the rack-test driver.  Capybara does a good job of abstracting the difference between in-browser tests that get driven by selenium-webdriver for test that can actually test that the JavaScript works in a browser but take a while to run and test that just run against the HTML produced by the controller/action, which run much faster but don't test JavaScript.  This means that the same set of scenarios and step definitions can be run in a browser or not without having to maintain duplicate sets of step definitions.